# Компрессия JS кода регуляркой на PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Компрессия JS кода регуляркой на PHP с использованием `preg_replace`(). Замена свойств и методов объектов на сокращенные их названия везде, кроме тех участков кода, где литеральный объект передается в один из методов объекта animation (свойства искомого литерального объекта нельзя заменять, т.к. в дальнейшем их значения передаются в соответствующие свойства style дом элемента).

Условный фрагмент JS кода:

```
App.func.animation.animateDomElement(document.getElementById("container"), {
    height: 0
}, 300, q);
var newObj = {
    height: 120
};
```

В этом примере, в подстроке "`var newObj={height:0};`" свойство height объекта должно быть заменено на новое имя, а в том литеральном объекте, который передается параметром в функцию, свойство должно остаться "как есть".

Второй день бьюсь над этой задачей, ничего не могу придумать.

PS: в JS коде, подготовленном для обработки регуляркой, разумеется, не будет ни лишних пробелов, ни табов, ни переносов строк.

Comment: Откуда брать новое имя? Или это не важно?

Comment: Неважно. Требуется заменить вхождение слова, если слева от него, до ближайшей слева точки с запятой, не встречается слово "animation"

Comment: @AlexWindHope анонимус не прощает! Даже когда кончаются комментарии. А вам совет - тролль пишется с двумя "лл". Даже название профессии не знаете толком. Ох.

Comment: Прошу уточнить: слово, которое надо заменять может быть в любом месте или только как в вопросе? Например какие из слов в этом примере надо заменить:  

    word1= word2;
    word3={
        word4:word5,
        word6:{
            word7:word13
        }
    };
    word8.word10.word11(word12);
Все word_N это либо переменная, либо метод/свойство объекта, а не условное обозначение чего-то абстрактного.